# C# read Data from 2 RS232(COM-Ports) independent

Tags: c#, serial-port

Is there any possibility to read Data from 2 RS232 Ports parallel?

It seems, that when i have 2 DataReceived-Events there are blocking each other.
I have also tried to set the SerialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold to a value of 50/100

```
class DataCollector
{

    private SerialPort _serialPort;
    List<String> Data;
    private bool _finished = false;
    private bool _handshake = true;

    public DataCollector(SerialPort serialPort, bool handshake=true)
    {
        Data = new List<String>();
        _serialPort = serialPort;

        _serialPort.DataReceived += SerialPortDataReceived;
        _handshake = handshake;
        if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            _serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
        }
    }

    ~DataCollector()
    {
        if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            _serialPort.DiscardInBuffer();
        }
        Data.Clear();
    }

    private void SerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_handshake == false)
        {

            String str =_serialPort.ReadLine();
            str.Insert(str.Length, "\n");

            Data.Add(str);


            if (Data.Count == 48)
            {
               _finished = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Char readedByte = (char)_serialPort.ReadByte();
            if ((readedByte != (char)5) && Data.Count == 0)
            {

                return;
            }
            if (readedByte.CompareTo((char)2) == 0)
            {
                readLine();
                sendAck();
            }
            else if (readedByte.CompareTo((char)5) == 0)
            {

                Data.Add(((char)5).ToString());
                sendAck();
            }
            else if (readedByte == (char)4)
            {
                _finished = true;
            }
        }

        private void sendAck()
        {
            if (_serialPort.IsOpen )
            {
                Byte[] bytes = {6};
                _serialPort.Write(bytes,0,1);
            }
        }
        private void readLine(){
            String str = _serialPort.ReadLine();
            Data.Add(str);
        }
    }
```

There are 2 defined in the Main:

```
_inputCollector = new DataCollector(_RS232Input);

_inputSecondCollector = new DataCollector(_RS232SecondInput, false);
```

Comment: How are they "blocking" each other? What threshold are you talking about?

Comment: I mean the threshold of the serialPort. SerialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold . I have read, that someone recommend to use it.

Comment: I can't see any blocking code. Can you add your `SerialPortDataReceived` method?

Comment: I don't see two ports here. And you haven't posted the `readLine()` method. The correct way to do this would be to set `ReceivedBytesThreshold` to `1` and use a FIFO buffer to store incoming bytes.

Comment: 1 serial port, and 1 thread?

Comment: It is 1 Thread with 2 Serial Ports. I have added more lines of Code

Comment: @demonking, I would seriously reconsider that implementation of only having a single thread - you should realistically have two separate threads each dealing with its own serial port (as currently, the program will 'freeze' if a large message was passed in - meaning the second port will be 'unusable' until this msg has finished).

Comment: @jbutler483 i will give it a try, i have thought that it would be enough to have 2 DataReceived-Events

Comment: single threading a multi-serial program is deffo not good practise.

Comment: @jbutler483 can you make an answer? Your Comment was the correct one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Comment**

I would seriously reconsider that implementation of only having a single thread - you should realistically have two separate threads each dealing with its own serial port (as currently, the program will 'freeze' if a large message was passed in - meaning the second port will be 'unusable' until this msg has finished).

---

**Answer**

Your system is currently running on a single thread. But implementing a muti-threading system - one which will listen to the first port, and another to listen to the second port. That way, they can both work at the same time.

Currently, (on this single thread) if data is received on one port, (and the other receives also) the thread will 'freeze' until the first message has been received/dealt with - and THEN will read the second port (that is, if it has not already timed out). So by using two threads, both ports can be written/read simultaneously (or, seem to be anyway).